# Importing Layer Styles in Photoshop Elements

Tags: layer-style, adobe-photoshop-elements

I know PSE does not have layer styles like PS does. However within the content panel you have preset options which are in fact layer styles you just cannot edit them as in PS. Now I have PS and a friend has PSE. Can I save my layer styles and import them into PSE for him to use as he would like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this but I came across this while doing some searching:

> 1 First make sure your folders are not "hidden":
>
> Click on "Start" and choose "My Computer." (Vista users: choose "Computer.") When a window pops up, click on the Tool menu at the top and choose Folder Options.
>
> When the Folder Options dialog box comes up, click on the View tab at the top.
>
> In the "Advanced Settings" section there's a folder called Hidden files and folders. Make sure "Show hidden files and folders" is selected. Click OK.
>
> 2 To add the layer style: Open the folder with the layer style.
>
> Right click on the layer style name and choose "Copy."
>
> 3 Click on the Start menu, then click on My Computer, and look for this path:
>
> In Vista and Windows 7 the path is:
>
> Start > Computer > Local Disk (C:) > Program Data > Adobe > Photoshop Elements > 7.0 > Photo Creations > Layer styles
>
> In Windows XP the path is:
>
> Start > Computer > Local Disk (C:) > Documents and Settings > All Users > Application Data > Adobe > Photoshop Elements > 7.0 > Photo Creations > layer styles
>
> Note: For Photoshop Elements 8, substitute 8.0 for 7.0 above. For Photoshop Elements 9, substitute 9.0 for the 7.0 above.
>
> For Photoshop Elements 10, the path is:
>
> Start > Computer > Local Disk (C:) > ProgramData > Adobe >Photoshop Elements >10.0 >Photo Creations > layer styles
>
> Once you're inside the Layer Styles folder, press Ctrl V to paste the layer style.
>
> Now go to: C:\ProgramData\Adobe\Photoshop Elements\10.0\Locale\en_us
>
> Locate the file called "Mediadatabase" and rename this file. You can make it OLDMediadatabase or anything you like. You are just renaming it so that Photoshop will rebuild the database. You do not want to delete it in case of the unlikely event that anything goes wrong. In this case, you can just change the name back to the original name.
>
> 4 Open PSE. It will take a while to rebuild the database.
>
> You can find the styles under the layer styles panel under "Show All."

[Source](http://www.designerdigitals.com/digital-scrapbooking/tips/questions/67/How+do+I+load+a+Layer+Style+file+%28ASL+or+.asl%29+into+Photoshop+Elements+7.0%2C+8.0%2C+9.0+or+10%3F+%28Windows%29)

Comment: That's a neat trick and good to know. I have a couple of non-designer associates who use PSE. I might want to use this with them one of these days.

Answer (score 0):

I use PS E 6, and all I have to do is right click on the PS Layer style file, and then click open, and wallah, it is already in my layer tray when it opens.
I can also keep adding layer styles this way, while PSE is open, and I need an extra style to load..